# Default image for img element

Tags: angular

I am using the img element like this with a pipe

```
<img [src]="filename | pathPipe" />
```

I would like to specify a default image which is used if the image path is broken. Can this be accomplished inside the template e.g. with a [default] property?

Comment: Can someone provide full code for using pathPipe ? I am just stuck

Comment: Hi @Santosh it's probably best to add a new question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `img` element provides an `error` event, so this should work fine:

```
<img [src]="filename | pathPipe" (error)="filename = '/path/to/fallback.jpg'" />
```

Comment: `pathPipe` was a special case @doorman used. You'd need to declare that pipe. `filename || pathPipe` boils down to `filename` unless `filename` is falsy. Just completely leave out `pathPipe` if you don't need to do any pipe transformation on filename. `|` and `||` have completely different meanings in JS and especially in angular templates

Answer (score 0):

Inside the pathPipe if you have something like an async call or downloading an image.
You can set a default value using startsWith inside a pipe func.